# Tangentbundle of the Tangentbundle

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I´m just getting started in differential geometry and the following question came up to me:

For any smooth manifold $\; M$ we can construct the so called tangentbundle $TM$. Since $TM$ is itself a smooth manifold we can construct the Tangentbundle of $TM$, let us call it $T(TM)$. My question is , is $T(TM)$ an importand object in differential geometry? We could think of the smooth sections of $T(TM)$ as smooth vector fields on $TM$, but are they of any importance?

Comment: Yes. For instance, a connection in the tangent bundle can be seen as a map $K: TTM \rightarrow TM$.